# How to await javascript fs.WriteStream close?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, pdfkit, node.js-fs

I am using nodejs [pdfkit](https://pdfkit.org/) to create a pdf document that I save inside of a file.

I would like to write my pdf inside of a file and make sure that the pdf has finished writting before exiting my function.

Here is my code:

```js
export default async function generate_pdf(params, filePath) {
    let doc = new PDFDocument({ size: "A4", margin: 50 });
    
    // Filling my pdf document...
    fillDoc(doc);

    // Finish the document and save it in a file
    doc.end();

    // Here a fs.WriteStream is created with automatic close.
    const writeStream = doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));
    // Here I would like to make sure that writeStream has finished before ending the function.
    // something like await waitForClose(writeStream);
    // before returning
    return filePath;
}
```

I know that according to [WriteStream documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatewritestreamoptions), there is an event 'close', that is emitted.

So I could do:

```js
writeStream.on('close', () => {
    // my code
});
```

But this is not solving my need, because I might create multiple files at the same time, I would like a way to make sure that all of the files has finished writing before exiting the function.

Thanks in advance if you can help :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do something like this:

```js
await new Promise(resolve => writeStream.on("close", resolve));
```